# How to create multiple subsets of dataframe by passing two variables

Tags: r

I am trying to split the data frame into multiple data-frames based on couple of properties :
a. Identify the colnames which contain punctuation mark i.e. (1),(2),(3) etc
b. Split the dataframe between two col locations identified for.e.g

- First Identified Location  = 2
- Second Identified Location = 11

  Expected Output  = NewDataSet[, 2:10] and so on

This is form of data which we receive monthly and we need to massage it to make it compatible with SQL database

```
structure(list(`Document ID` = c(159812L, 159822L, 170083L), 
`Rental unit (1)` = 1:3, `Gross area` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1,000.00", 
"1,001.00", "1,002.00"), class = "factor"), Unit = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "sq ft", class = "factor"), `Net area` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), Unit = c(NA, 
NA, NA), `Floor no.` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), 
Unit = c(NA, NA, NA), `Start date` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("6/3/2008", 
"7/20/2007", "n/a"), class = "factor"), `End date` = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("6/29/2025", "6/30/2028", "n/a"), class = "factor"), 
`Rental unit (2)` = 3:5, `Gross area` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1,000.00", 
"1,001.00", "1,002.00"), class = "factor"), Unit = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "sq ft", class = "factor"), `Net area` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), Unit = c(NA, 
NA, NA), `Floor no.` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), 
Unit = c(NA, NA, NA), `Start date` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("6/3/2008", 
"7/20/2007", "n/a"), class = "factor"), `End date` = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("6/29/2025", "6/30/2028", "n/a"), class = "factor"), 
`Rental unit (3)` = 5:7, `Gross area` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1,000.00", 
"1,001.00", "1,002.00"), class = "factor"), Unit = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "sq ft", class = "factor"), `Net area` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), Unit = c(NA, 
NA, NA), `Floor no.` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), 
Unit = c(NA, NA, NA), `Start date` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("6/3/2008", 
"7/20/2007", "n/a"), class = "factor"), `End date` = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("6/29/2025", "6/30/2028", "n/a"), class = "factor"), 
Longitude = c(NA, NA, NA), Latitude = c(NA, NA, NA), `Orga Unit` = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("SESAC and Sublease", " 2018 - Real Estate Lease Demo"
), class = "factor"), `Workflow state` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "R1 + R2 done", class = "factor"), `Name of DocSet` = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("ii - 1000 - Target", "SESAC", "Stop & Shop executed lease 060308"
), class = "factor"), `Language of DocSet` = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("en", "en_US"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

multiple dataframes based on column location

I started with  below mentioned code :

```
newFile <-  read.csv("sample.csv", check.names = FALSE)
vecLoc <- c(grep("[[:punct:]]", colnames(newFile)))
```

Comment: as far as I can tell you want the columns where the name is 'Rental unit (1)',  'Rental unit (2)',  'Rental unit (3)'  which are in positions `c(2,11,20)`. And so you want columns 2:10, 11:19 and 20:ncol(data)?

Comment: @which_command   Yes ,you identified the problem correctly. Is there a way to break the data by columns in r ?

Answer (score 1):

```
data=structure(list(`Document ID` = c(159812L, 159822L, 170083L), 
`Rental unit (1)` = 1:3, `Gross area` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1,000.00", 
"1,001.00", "1,002.00"), class = "factor"), Unit = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "sq ft", class = "factor"), `Net area` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), Unit = c(NA, 
NA, NA), `Floor no.` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), 
Unit = c(NA, NA, NA), `Start date` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("6/3/2008", 
"7/20/2007", "n/a"), class = "factor"), `End date` = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("6/29/2025", "6/30/2028", "n/a"), class = "factor"), 
`Rental unit (2)` = 3:5, `Gross area` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1,000.00", 
"1,001.00", "1,002.00"), class = "factor"), Unit = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "sq ft", class = "factor"), `Net area` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), Unit = c(NA, 
NA, NA), `Floor no.` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), 
Unit = c(NA, NA, NA), `Start date` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("6/3/2008", 
"7/20/2007", "n/a"), class = "factor"), `End date` = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("6/29/2025", "6/30/2028", "n/a"), class = "factor"), 
`Rental unit (3)` = 5:7, `Gross area` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1,000.00", 
"1,001.00", "1,002.00"), class = "factor"), Unit = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "sq ft", class = "factor"), `Net area` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), Unit = c(NA, 
NA, NA), `Floor no.` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "n/a", class = "factor"), 
Unit = c(NA, NA, NA), `Start date` = structure(1:3, .Label = c("6/3/2008", 
"7/20/2007", "n/a"), class = "factor"), `End date` = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("6/29/2025", "6/30/2028", "n/a"), class = "factor"), 
Longitude = c(NA, NA, NA), Latitude = c(NA, NA, NA), `Orga Unit` = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("SESAC and Sublease", " 2018 - Real Estate Lease Demo"
), class = "factor"), `Workflow state` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "R1 + R2 done", class = "factor"), `Name of DocSet` = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("ii - 1000 - Target", "SESAC", "Stop & Shop executed lease 060308"
), class = "factor"), `Language of DocSet` = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("en", "en_US"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

So the way that I found the locations of the columns that you want is as follows:

```
split_locations=grep(colnames(data),pattern = "[(*)]") # the strategy that you provided in your Q identified columns with 'Floor no.' in them...
```

So from the above created `split_locations` I have column numbers `c(2,11,20)`- hope this is correct.

This is only 3 splits so you could just simply do:

```
df1=data[,2:10]
df2=data[,11:19]
df3=data[,20:ncol(data)]
```

However if the above is too simple for the actual analysis that your doing. You could do the following:

```
split_locations=c(split_locations,ncol(data)) #add the final number to the end of split_locations
iterate_to=length(split_locations)-1 #specify how far we'll be iterating
for(i in 1:iterate_to){ #from 1 to the second last element of split_locations
    assign(paste0('df',i), data[,c(split_locations[i]:split_locations[i+1])]) #use the command 'assign' to assign data to 'df1', 'df2' etc.
}
```

The above code assigns the split columns to different dataframes: columns 2:10 to `df1`, 11:19 to `df2` etc. It does so by taking column numbers `i` to `i+1`.
Hope this makes sense.

If you wanted you could also write the split columns to their own text files with `write.table(data[,c(split_locations[i]:split_locations[i+1])],file=paste0('data',i,'.txt'),....)`

Comment: @ which_command  thank you that is exactly what i was looking